# How can I unit test components that depend on the RC3 router?

Tags: typescript, angular, jasmine

I am trying to get unit tests that worked with RC1 working with the "new new" router. How can I achieve this on `3.0.0-alpha.8`?

My dependencies:

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
```

---

The component **that I would like to test** that uses the `routerLink` directive:

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-topmenu',
    template: require('./app-topmenu.tpl.html'),
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class TopMenu {
```

```
<nav class="app-top-menu">
    <a *ngFor="let link of links" [routerLink]="link.route">{{link.text}}</a>
</nav>
```

---

Previously, with rc1, I was using something like this to unit-test my component:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {SpyLocation} from '@angular/common/testing';
import {Router, RouteRegistry, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {RootRouter} from '@angular/router-deprecated/src/router';

describe('Router link capabilities', () => {
    beforeEachProviders(() => [
        RouteRegistry,
        { provide: Location, useClass: SpyLocation },
        { provide: ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, useValue: TestComponent },
        { provide: Router, useClass: RootRouter }
    ]);

    it('creates routerLinks with the expected URLs', fakeAsync(
        inject([TestComponentBuilder, Location], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder, spyLocation: SpyLocation) => {
            tcb.overrideTemplate(TestComponent, `
                <app-top-menu [links]='[
                    { text: "A", route: ["/TestA/TestB/TestC"] },
                    { text: "B", route: ["/TestA", "TestB", "TestC"] }
                ]'></app-top-menu>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            `).createAsync(TestComponent)
            .then((fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>) => {
                fixture.detectChanges();
                spyLocation.simulateUrlPop('url-a/url-b/url-c');
                tick();
                fixture.detectChanges();
                let nativeLinks: HTMLAnchorElement[] = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');

                expect(nativeLinks.length).toBe(2);
                expect(nativeLinks[0].textContent).toBe('A');
                expect(nativeLinks[1].textContent).toBe('B');
            });
        })
    ));
});
```

When I try to just switch the `routerLink` imports from `@angular/router-deprecated` to importing `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` from `@angular/router`, I receive an error:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Platforms have to be created via `createPlatform`!
```

All documentation I can find online about testing the "new new" router and the *createPlatform* message refers to providing `ROUTER_FAKE_PROVIDERS` which appears to be included in rc2, but gone with rc3:

```
import {ROUTER_FAKE_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router/testing';
// ^ [ts] Cannot find module '@angular/router/testing'.
```

Searching through the compiled `.d.ts` files in `node_modules/@angular/router` folder, I did also not find any references to testing/mocks/fakes.

Did anyone migrate to rc3 and get this working yet?

Comment: Take a look on these tests https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/test/router.spec.ts

Answer (score 3):

To test the RC3 (3.0.0-alpha.*) router, you need to do a couple of things differently from how the router was set up in previous versions.

You need to define a `RouterConfig` like this:

```
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';

export const APP_ROUTES : RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', component: AppComponent},
    // more paths
];

export const APP_ROUTE_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES)  
];
```

then in your test file

```
import {ActivatedRoute, RouterConfig, Router} from '@angular/router';

class MockRouter { createUrlTree() {} }
class MockActivatedRoute { }

beforeEachProviders(() => [
  provide(Router, { useClass: MockRouter }),
  provide(ActivatedRoute, { useClass: MockActivatedRoute }),
]);

describe(){
   // etc
}
```

Your router is now testable.

for RC4:

```
import {ActivatedRoute, RouterConfig, Router} from '@angular/router';

class MockRouter { createUrlTree() {} }
class MockActivatedRoute { }



describe(){
  beforeEach(() => [
      addProviders([
          provide(Router, { useClass: MockRouter }),
          provide(ActivatedRoute, { useClass: MockActivatedRoute }),
      ]);
  ]);
  //etc
}
```

Comment: But this does not let me test a component which depends on the actual `routerLink` functionality, does it? I don't want to test the router, I want to test a component that uses the router. Please see the second (now bold) paragraph. This was possible with `SpyLocation` and `MockLocationStrategy` before, but `MockLocationStrategy` is not exported in rc4.

Comment: So you want to test that when a link is clicked it navigates to the correct page? If so, you can use the `isCurrentPathEqualTo(path: string, query: string = ''): boolean` method of SpyLocation. Simulate a link click with JS and then use the expect with this method. I believe you are correct in thinking this will not work. In work, we have a wrapper around the router which stores the routes we have navigated to, so we test that that route log.

Comment: How would you mock route parameters with `ActivatedRoute`?